The AJAX request expects JSON but gets HTML, causing a 404 error

function checkCustomersAccount() {
            console.log("checkCustomersAccount called");

            var customersAccountReg = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]{5,10}$/;
            var account = document.getElementById("customersAccountInput").value;
            var customersAccountMsgSpan = document.getElementById("customersAccountMsg");

            if (!customersAccountReg.test(account)) {
                customersAccountMsgSpan.innerText = "Format does not match";
                return false;
            }

            var encodedAccount = encodeURIComponent(account);
            var requestUrl = "/customers/checkAccountUsed?account=" + encodedAccount;
            console.log("Request URL:", requestUrl);

            fetch(requestUrl, {
                method: 'GET',
                headers: {
                    'Accept': 'application/json'
                }
            })
                .then(response => {
                    if (!response.ok) {
                        throw new Error('Network response was not ok');
                    }
                    return response.json();
                })
                .then(result => {
                    console.log("Result:", result);
                   
                    if (result.available) {
                        customersAccountMsgSpan.innerText = "";
                    } else {
                        customersAccountMsgSpan.innerText = "Account already exists";
                    }
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.error("Fetch error:", error);
                    customersAccountMsgSpan.innerText = "Request failed";
                });
        }

<form action="/customers/regist" method="post" onsubmit="return verify(this)">
    <table class="boder">
        <tr>
            <td class="col1">客戶帳號: <br>
                </td>
            <td class="col2"><input type="text" id="customersAccountInput" name="account"       class="textfield" onblur="checkCustomersAccount()"
                                    placeholder="5-10位大小寫英文及數字組合" style="font-size: 12px"/>
                <span id="customersAccountMsg" class="msg"></span>
            </td>
</form>

//framework SpringBoot
@RestController
public class CustomersController {
    @GetMapping(value = "/customers/checkAccountUsed")
    @CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
    public ResponseEntity<Result> checkAccountUsed(@RequestParam("account") String account) {
        System.out.println("Received account" + account);
        Customers customers = customerService.getCustomersByAccount(account);


        Result result = (customers != null) ? new Result(false) : new Result(true);

        return ResponseEntity.ok()
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)  
                .body(result);
    }
}

I have confirmed that the backend works correctly using Postman, but the frontend webpage is not functioning properly. I want to know where the issue might be.Thank!
Try:
1.Use Postman check
2.rebuild Tomcat version-10.1.21
3.use XMLHttpRequest but dosen't work
fetch(requestUrl, {//Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
method: 'GET',
headers: {
'Accept': 'application/json'
}
})
Request URL:
http://localhost:8080/customers/checkAccountUsed?account=cutes5566
Request Method:
GET
Status Code:
404 Not Found
Remote Address:
[::1]:8080
Referrer Policy:
strict-origin-when-cross-origin
Response Headers
connection:
keep-alive
content-language:
en
content-length:
782
content-type:
text/html;charset=utf-8
date:
Thu, 12 Sep 2024 14:05:14 GMT
keep-alive:
timeout=20
Request Headers
accept:
application/json
referer:
http://localhost:8080/regist.html
sec-ch-ua:
"Chromium";v="128", "Not;A=Brand";v="24", "
Google Chrome";v="128"
sec-ch-ua-mobile:
?0
sec-ch-ua-platform:
"Windows"
user-agent:
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/128.0.0.0 Safari/537.36

sorry everyone is a stupid question
I forget the spring boot html or else resource need put at resource file, it would not to create a new modules for web.
